# OS.Path works from Jypyter note book, not from standalone script

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.path

I have a Jyputer note book with the following code

```
import os
execution_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd()+'\\', "BillingInfo.xlsx")
print(os.getcwd())
print(execution_path)
```

The output of this code is

```
C:\Users\mys2kor
C:\Users\mys2kor\BillingInfo.xlsx
```

I copy this **exact** same file on to my desktop as a python script (file name OSpath.py) & run it from Anaconda prompt & the output is

```
C:\
C:\\BillingInfo.xlsx
```

Why is this difference? What am i doing wrong? I want the same output as the Jupyter note book even when I run the script independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.getcwd()` return the current directory of a running process. 
When you are using jupyter, the current running process is where your notebook is located.
When you run a python script, the location of the current running process is the directory from which you executed your python command here your anaconda prompt which is located in your `C:\`.

If you need the file absolute path, I'd recommend you use the `__file__` value when you are outside a notebook.

Comment: How do i use `__file__`?

Comment: as you will use a python variable :
```my_path = __file__``` or ```print(__file__)```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Your' answer help me resolve my situation.